# Data collection best practice using REST APis

Tags: rest, jsonpath

Consider I have a data collection API that is using a resource as follows,

```
{
    user: {
        id:"c5667fb4-2348-4ccc-afc4-2309077a09ad"
        documents :[
            {
                type:"PASSPORT",
                value:"1234"
                issue_date:"11/11/2011"
            },
            {
                type:"DRIVING_LICENSE",
                value:"5678"
                issue_date:"11/11/2001"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

For a given user that a client is interested in, I need to be able to evaluate and respond through my API and ask for any of the missing documents - Like for example a user might have provided only PASSPORT on creation time so I need to now ask only for DRIVING_LICENSE.

For this I was thinking of a controller endpoint(like an "evaluate") to be able to send a response that indicates what data the user is missing.

the client can invoke **POST: /evaluate/c5667fb4-2348-4ccc-afc4-2309077a09ad**
and now say that this user is missing DRIVING_LICENSE the response should indicate what is missing like follows - I am using json path to define what I am looking for

```
{
    required_data:[
        {
            path:"user.documents[?(@.type=="DRIVING_LICENSE")].type"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is this a reasonable way to express this requirement or is there a more correct way to do this?

Comment: I feel that the general title of the question is too broad. Are both passpord AND driving license necessary in your use case? If yes, should partial uploads of such documents be supported? If so, you need a way to attach the document to the initial request. There are a couple of ways to achive this. In HTML i.e. you return a form to tell the client what information is needed/missing. By using custom, over-generic (plain JSON) media-types a client needs out-of-band information on processing such a request, which is a bit against RESTs intention TBH.

Comment: Apologies if the title is not specific enough. The use case here is something like the user is trying to apply for a new product which requires a some more information to be collected as generally(for us) the information provided at onboarding(user creation) is pretty minimal. To give some more context, this is for a mid tier component that houses what data is needed for a specific product and hence I was alluding towards how to do this via APIs.

Comment: In general the best advice in terms of REST architecture given is to design the interaction flow as if you deal with a browser-based service that ships HTML pages. You might replace HTML with JSON, though the important segments like forms and such should be present in this representation format as well. The syntax used as well as the semantics of elements should be defined as closely as possible to avoid confusion. Ideally you'd also register such a media type with [IANA](https://www.iana.org/form/media-types)

Answer (score 1):

If some mandatory information is missing in the request then this is error case and in this case it is better to provide 400 error HTTP code and error response body. So something like this

```
HTTP Error Code: 400
Error json body:
{
    "errorCode": "Validation",
    "message": "Driving license is required"
}
```